# How to dplyr::arrange groups within a df by the mean of group measure?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, dplyr, group-summaries

Building off of Kara Woo's https://stackoverflow.com/a/26555424/9350837 answer, I'm looking to sort my grouped df by the mean of respective groups summarized measure, `vizCredPrcnt`.

This is my code, thus far,

```
credData <- ReShapeAdCredSubset %>%
group_by(CredentialQ, year) %>%
summarise(vizCredPrcnt = (sum(credential_wIndiv, na.rm = TRUE) / (sum(credential_wAll, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
arrange(CredentialQ, year, desc(mean(vizCredPrcnt)))
```

This is the error I get,

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
>   incorrect size (1) at position 3, expecting : 144

This is my tibble, and a visual of the grouped mean I'm looking to sort by,

**grouped tibble to arrange**

[image]

Happy to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Please provide your data

Comment: Data as a picture is not very helpful, we can't copy that into our session to play with.

Comment: You can't arrange by the mean, because the mean is one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try creating a variable that specifies the mean of the visCredPrcnt variable by CredentialQ group, and then pass that in the arrange call like so:

```
credData <- ReShapeAdCredSubset %>%
    group_by(CredentialQ, year) %>%
    summarise(vizCredPrcnt = (sum(credential_wIndiv, na.rm = TRUE) / (sum(credential_wAll, na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(CredentialQ) %>%
    summarize(meanVizCredPrcnt = mean(visCredPrcnt, na.rm = T)) %>%
    arrange(CredentialQ, year, desc(meanVizCredPrcnt))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Nick! Your suggestion got me on the right path, as well as nicola's https://stackoverflow.com/a/44174523/9350837, suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, Nick! Your suggestion got me on the right path, as well as nicola's https://stackoverflow.com/a/44174523/9350837, suggestion.

I took both of your suggestions, and smooshed them together for this, which does the trick!

```
credData <- ReShapeAdCredSubset %>%
group_by(CredentialQ, year) %>%
summarise(vizCredPrcnt = (sum(credential_wIndiv, na.rm = TRUE) / (sum(credential_wAll, na.rm = TRUE)))) 

credData <- credData %>%
mutate(meanViz = mean(vizCredPrcnt, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
group_by(CredentialQ) %>%
arrange(desc(meanViz))
```

Thanks again!